# Mock function with wrong behavior still pass

Tags: go, testing

I am writing a test for a function that depends on other functions. I use `Gomock` library to mock those dependencies' behaviors, this is one of them:

```
&mock.UseCaseToDependOn{
    UpdateStatusFuncMock: func(ID data.ID) ([]*ObjectsToReturn, error) {
        return case.in.updateStatusFuncReturnsObjects, case.in.updateStatusFuncReturnsError
    },
},
```

However, on code review, I realized that the `UpdateStatusFuncMock` mocking function that uses state machine pattern is returning illogical data based on the input, however, the test still passed nicely.

This is really odd to me, cause I believe that the test should fail in this case.

Also on other side, if I provide the data that just follow the logic then:

- First, I need to understand the internal behavior of the functions that my test depends on. Is it a good thing or bad thing?
- Second, I think that doing this just create false positive, since the test still passes for mocking function with wrong behavior.

Is it good to create mocking functions with input and output must abide by existing logic?

Comment: "Is it good to create mocking functions with [whatever]". No. IMHO mocking is an exceptional bad testing practice (except for some very special cases). As you noted mocking often tends to test internal implementation details. Some languages cannot be tested without mocking but I think using stubs or fakes is easy in Go and leads to cleaner an better tests.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it is important to differentiate between white box and black box testing.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-black-box-testing-vs-white-box-testing/

Depending on which one you're trying to do, follow the best approach, as the previous comment says, it is clean and usually better to use fakes or stubs.

You can create a set of tests with stubs returning error and another one with expected outputs.